# Windows 7 pro- Normal boot up, but slow network login

Tags: networking, windows-7, login

got a question I'd like a little advice on.

I have a user on out network who's got a laptop that boots up at a normal speed to the login page, but once he enters in his login credentials the system takes an extremely long time for him to get to the desktop. I ran a test on the hard drive and it's working properly, I cleared the temporary files he had, and I adjusted his boot options so he doesn't have so many programs starting up when he logs in, but he still seems to be having the issue. i tried logging in as myself on his system and, although the login process seems to be faster than his, I get a bit of a delay as well. His profile is local, and the systems on out network aren't set up for roaming profiles, so it wouldn't be pulling anything from the server to populate his desktop on login. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check and see if he has any policies or logon scripts that are failing and slowing things down.

Comment: I didn't think about logon scripts, but I'll definitely check it out along with any policy conflicts. Thanks so much!

Comment: capture a boot trace with xbootmgr and share it: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: Check your user's DNS settings. Make sure they are pointing to valid Windows Domain Controllers.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar issue before, It was a network issue, at the users desk it never worked but at mine it worked fine, but the issue was that because of this it took to long to connect to AD and pull down Group Policies.